# Only 1.5v from a new doorbell transformer 16-30vac transformer

Tags: electrical, doorbell

I installed a new Hampton Bay doorbell transformer and am only getting 1.5v at 60hz at the screws. What could be causing this, and how would I go about troubleshooting the issue?

Comment: Is there voltage on the primary side of the transformer?

Comment: is there anythinf conneted to the transformer while you are measuring?

Comment: Yes there is primary voltage and nothing is connected while measuring.

Comment: I've got ten bucks that says he's measuring DC when he should be measuring AC.

Answer (score 1):

1. What do you mean by "16-30 VAC" transformer? Does it have two secondaries? What model is it?
2. Is the transformer *secondary* connected to the wires? There could be a short circuit in the house wiring. Disconnect one wire from the secondary and check the voltage on the transformer *without load*. If it's in the correct range, the fault is in the house wiring.
3. Put a load across the primary, such as a small light bulb, to determine that there is actually 120 (or 240) VAC. A digital meter will not give a correct reading because its load is too low.

If it has full mains voltage in, and only 1.5 VAC out with no load, the transformer is defective.

Comment: I suspect the OP means "16V 30 VA" transformer.

Comment: @Armand, yes, I agree that is likely, but ask for confirmation.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I meant.

Comment: After testing I think there is a short in the wire.

Comment: @AaronSagray, perhapsthe original transformer is still good, too. Look for the short in the obvious places, first: 1. the outdoor push-button can get stuck *on* -- disconnect one wire at the button, and check the transformer secondary voltage with both wires attached to its terminal; if 16 or so VAC, it's the button. 2. Behind the chime or annunciator is a junction box -- look for bare connections, where tape or wire nuts have come off. 3. Has there been any recent construction, where a nail might have mashed or pierced the bell wires?

Comment: I'm wondering if the transformer input has somehow gotten connected to the output of another transformer.

Comment: @HotLicks, **very** unlikely this is due to two transformers connected together. 1. *Where* would this hypothetical transformer be? Who would have added it? 2. If they were standard 16 VAC bell transformers, in-phase, the output would be the normal 16 VAC. If out of phase, the smoke issuing from one or both would be clear indication!

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - A 16v transformer with it's inputs connected to the output of another 16v transformer would have an output of about 2 volts.  I admit that this is unlikely, and would be impossible if the person has reasonable knowledge of electricity and wiring, but the OP doesn't appear to be very knowledgeable in this area of technology.